# Ansible Role to Check Health of a host group

Tags: ansible

After running several plays in my playbook, I want to verify the deployment of my apps.

In one of my roles, I have the following task, adds created ec2 instances to hosts as 'launched':

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  local_action: add_host hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
  with_items: ec2.instances
```

Here is my main playbook, `site.yml` :

```
......
Run some plays for deployment and provisioning
......
# Validate the deployment by reaching from the local machine
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  roles:
  - validate_deployment
```

Here is my `verify_deployment/tasks/main.yml`

```
- name: Validate the deployment. Launched is my dynamically created host group
  uri: url="https://{{ inventory_hostname }}:8000"
  with_items: launched
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you registering "launched?"  What sort of action do you want?  Look at the official examples http://docs.ansible.com/uri_module.html#examples

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect how I create launched. Cheers

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get some error? Some unintended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but your `verify_deployment` role will not work, as you use the `inventory_hostname` variable instead of `item`. You should probably write:

```
- name: Validate the deployment. Launched is my dynamically created host group
  uri: url="https://{{ item }}:8000"
  with_items: launched
```